# Gnu screen: Problems with %F

Tags: gnu-screen, caption

I'm trying to set region captions to list all windows on active (focused) screen region, and only the title for other regions. For example:

```
caption always "%?%F %w %: %n*%t %?"
```

should display something like this:

```
1 Bash  2*Vim  3 Ipython      |  3*Ipython
```

However, the full list is displayed on both regions. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the `%? *first part* %:%?` will evaluate to true if one or more %escapes evaluates to a non-empty string. In your example %w expands to a list, making the *first part* true regardless of the %F modifier.

The closest I can get to circumventing this "flaw" is below, but it only gives the active and inactive regions different colors, not different content.

```
caption always '%?%F%{rk}%:%{wk}%n %?%F%:(%t) %?  %?'
```